# Is it possible to configure the FileLogRoute?

Tags: config, logging

I am trying to debug a "clean template cache" task that gets stuck. However, it only happens intermittently, and whenever I notice any errors has already been rotated out of the log files.

Is there a way to set the `maxLogFiles` of the `FileLogRoute`?  either through the config files, or through php code in a plugin?

(Setting `$rotateByCopy` to true would also be nice!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not without hacking the core files.

It's on our list to make log routing more configurable for Craft 3, though.